# PF blocking out Flags [FP.]

Tags: freebsd, pf

On a [FreeBSD 12](https://www.freebsd.org/) server, I started to notice that [pf](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/filter.html) is blocking out having `Flags [FP.]`, the logs are flooded with something like this:

```
00:00:00.000004 rule 2/0(match): block out on bge0: 213.59.241.172.80 > 162.158.59.122.48894: Flags [FP.], seq 0:187, ack 1, win 65535, length 187: HTTP
00:00:00.000004 rule 2/0(match): block out on bge0: 213.59.241.172.80 > 141.101.98.92.16036: Flags [FP.], seq 0:187, ack 1, win 65535, length 187: HTTP
00:00:00.000004 rule 2/0(match): block out on bge0: 213.59.241.172.80 > 162.158.89.53.45136: Flags [FP.], seq 0:187, ack 1, win 65535, length 187: HTTP
00:00:00.000004 rule 2/0(match): block out on bge0: 213.59.241.172.80 > 162.158.88.60.43016: Flags [FP.], seq 0:187, ack 1, win 65535, length 187: HTTP
00:00:00.000004 rule 2/0(match): block out on bge0: 213.59.241.172.80 > 162.158.89.101.58320: Flags [FP.], seq 0:187, ack 1, win 65535, length 187: HTTP
00:00:00.000004 rule 2/0(match): block out on bge0: 213.59.241.172.80 > 162.158.179.50.21756: Flags [FP.], seq 0:187, ack 1, win 65535, length 187: HTTP
00:00:00.000004 rule 2/0(match): block out on bge0: 213.59.241.172.80 > 162.158.91.39.18516: Flags [FP.], seq 0:187, ack 1, win 65535, length 187: HTTP
00:00:00.000004 rule 2/0(match): block out on bge0: 213.59.241.172.80 > 162.158.90.202.25684: Flags [FP.], seq 0:187, ack 1, win 65535, length 187: HTTP
00:00:00.000004 rule 2/0(match): block out on bge0: 213.59.241.172.80 > 172.69.226.63.52316: Flags [FP.], seq 0:187, ack 1, win 65535, length 187: HTTP
00:00:00.000003 rule 2/0(match): block out on bge0: 213.59.241.172.80 > 162.158.90.202.25662: Flags [FP.], seq 0:187, ack 1, win 65535, length 187: HTTP
00:00:00.000005 rule 2/0(match): block out on bge0: 213.59.241.172.80 > 198.41.242.26.29508: Flags [FP.], seq 0:187, ack 1, win 65535, length 187: HTTP
```

Any idea of why this could be happening?

Rule 2 is

```
@2 block drop log all
```

Server running mainly `HAproxy` and these settings on `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
debug.debugger_on_panic=0
debug.trace_on_panic=1
kern.ipc.shmmax=2147483648
kern.ipc.somaxconn=32768
kern.panic_reboot_wait_time=0
net.inet.icmp.drop_redirect=1
net.inet.icmp.icmplim=10
net.inet.icmp.log_redirect=0
net.inet.icmp.maskrepl=0
net.inet.ip.accept_sourceroute=0
net.inet.ip.random_id=1
net.inet.ip.redirect=0
net.inet.ip.sourceroute=0
net.inet.tcp.blackhole=2
net.inet.tcp.drop_synfin=1
net.inet.tcp.fast_finwait2_recycle=1
net.inet.tcp.finwait2_timeout=1000
net.inet.tcp.msl=2500
net.inet.tcp.recvbuf_auto=1
net.inet.tcp.recvbuf_inc=16384
net.inet.tcp.recvbuf_max=134217728
net.inet.tcp.sendbuf_auto=1
net.inet.tcp.sendbuf_inc=16384
net.inet.tcp.sendbuf_max=134217728
net.inet.udp.blackhole=1
security.bsd.see_other_gids=0
security.bsd.see_other_uids=0
security.bsd.see_jail_proc=0
security.bsd.stack_guard_page=1
security.bsd.unprivileged_proc_debug=0
security.bsd.unprivileged_read_msgbuf=0
net.inet.tcp.mssdflt=1460
net.inet.tcp.minmss=536
net.inet.tcp.syncache.rexmtlimit=0
net.inet.ip.maxfragpackets=0
net.inet.ip.maxfragsperpacket=0
net.inet.tcp.abc_l_var=44
net.inet.tcp.initcwnd_segments=44
kern.ipc.maxsockbuf=614400000
net.inet.tcp.syncookies=1
net.inet.tcp.tso=1
kern.random.fortuna.minpoolsize=256
net.inet.tcp.isn_reseed_interval=123
```

These are the `pf` rules after adding a `pass` before `block` (rule 2 now is rule 7)

```
scrub in all no-df max-mss 1440 fragment reassemble
block drop in log on ! bge0 inet6 from 2001:4ba0:85a3:105::/64 to any
block drop in log on bge0 inet6 from fe80::eeeb:b8ff:fe87:9514 to any
block drop in log inet6 from <__automatic_2bacaf44_0:7> to any
block drop in log on ! bge0 inet from 213.59.241.128/25 to any
block drop in log inet from 213.59.241.172 to any
pass quick from <allow:5> to any flags S/SA keep state (if-bound)
block drop log all
block drop quick from <banned:0> to any
block drop quick from <bruteforce:0> to any
block drop in log quick from no-route to any
block drop in quick on bge0 proto tcp all flags FPU/FSRPAUEW
block drop in quick on bge0 proto tcp all flags FSRPAUEW/FSRPAUEW
block drop in quick on bge0 proto tcp all flags FSRAU/FSRPAUEW
block drop in quick on bge0 proto tcp all flags /FSRPAUEW
block drop in quick on bge0 proto tcp all flags SR/SR
block drop in quick on bge0 proto tcp all flags FS/FS
pass in quick on bge0 proto tcp from any to any port = http flags S/SA keep state (if-bound)
pass in quick on bge0 proto tcp from any to any port = https flags S/SA keep state (if-bound)
pass in quick on bge0 proto tcp from any to any port = 2222 flags S/SA keep state (if-bound)
pass in quick proto ipencap all keep state (if-bound)
pass inet proto icmp all icmp-type echoreq keep state (if-bound)
pass inet proto icmp all icmp-type unreach keep state (if-bound)
pass proto ipv6-icmp all keep state (if-bound)
pass out quick proto tcp all flags S/SA keep state (if-bound)
pass out all flags S/SA keep state (if-bound)
```

For this line:

```
pass quick from <allow:5> to any flags S/SA keep state (if-bound)
```

Allow is a `table`, something like:

```
group1 = "10.0.0.4"
group2 = "5.19.152.31 95.116.0.173:"
table <allow> { $group1, $group2 }
```

Something that I notice is that even I have the `pass` before the `block`:

```
pass quick from <allow:5> to any flags S/SA keep state (if-bound)
block drop log all
```

Some "allowed" groups are beeing blocked, for example:

```
00:00:00.589761 rule 7/0(match): block out on bge0: 213.59.241.172.4567 > 5.19.152.31.61847: Flags [RP.], seq 2:81, ack 0, win 0, length 79
```

The `rule 7` is the `block drop log all`, In this case, `5.19.152.31` is in the `allow` table but is in being blocked

Therefore wondering how to full allow/skip certain IP's, network ranges before getting block.

Comment: 1) Do you have there only one interface ? 2) does the state table have enough free entries ?

Comment: and I don’t like this MASSIVE sysctl tampering with default oid values around net.inet. Are you sure about what you’re doing here ? Because if you’re the author of these tweaks then you have to be experienced enough to deal with pf on your own; if you’re not the author of these then it’s a cargo cult.

Comment: the server has 4 interfaces, currently only using one `bge0`, regarding the sysctl settings any hint, I have being tunning `net.inet.tcp.msl` but don't think could justify the block out rule

Comment: Show ys traffic on other interfaces then, if they are up.

Comment: other interfaces are down

Comment: Show us the `pfctl --vvvs rules` output then.

Comment: @drookie, I updated the question also with some findings, for some reasons pf is blocking out traffic from an allowed defined table

Comment: What is the reason of `FPU/FSRPAUEW` and subsequent flags rules ? Are you trying to enhance the builtin pf sanity checks ? Why ? Do these rules have non-zero counts ?

Comment: If all of the interfaces except bge0 are down why using `if-bound` ? Where is the `set skip on lo0` rule (do you filter localhost ?) ? And so on. Your pf.conf looks acrually weird. Like extremely weird. The more I know about it the more questions I have. Rewrite it from scratch and see if it helps. I also recommend flushing out all the pseudo-tweaks from sysctl. Looks like you have absolutely no idea what they do.

Comment: `pfctl -vvvsr` don't show the skip, I indeed have it for the whole group `set skip on {lo}`, the `FPU/FSRPAUEW` help against some nmap scans but that blocks only incoming traffic, the question is more about the block in the outgoing traffic

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Pf's view of those TCP streams doesn't match the peers TCP/IP-stacks's.

I'd recommend …

1. checking out whether `state-mismatch` is getting increased when
   you're seeing those entries in the logs, for e. g.:

   ```
   sudo pfctl -s info | fgrep -- state-mismatch
   ```

   of course, check other `-s info` counters as well, make sure you don't have states pruned due to mem. pressure, for e. g..
2. getting rid of `scrub` altogether at least while you're debugging
   that issue.

If there's anything more than just log cluttering and-or you badly want that traffic to flow freely, not being ditched by Pf, you can *add* explicit `pass … no state` catching rule, tailored to your preferences of course.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend starting with this configuration (yeah, I skipped mtu tweaks until your explanation why 1440 size is chosen), since yours is a total mess:

```
oif = "bge0"

# because you don't want to filter localhost
set skip on lo0

# because it's a default rule
block drop log all

# because you don't want to drop ICMP
pass proto icmp all

# or ICMP6
pass proto ipv6-icmp all

# okay then
block drop quick from <banned:0> to any
block drop quick from <bruteforce:0> to any

# because you need ssh (is the 2222 new port for ssh ? Jeezus, use blacklistd)
pass in on $oif proto tcp from any to any port 22

# because flags S/SA and keep state is the default
pass in on $oif proto tcp from any to any port { 80, 443, 2222 }

# because you need to configure both ends with ipinip, so why bother about states
pass in on $oif proto ipencap all

# because you want to allow all the locally-originated sessions
pass out all
```

Comment: What is the difference between using only `block in log all` vs `block log all` and need to use `pass out all`?

Comment: Well it's obvious - `block in log all` blocks everything inbound, while `block log all` blocks outbound too. `pass out all` passes everything out locally-originated. Is there anyone from technical personnel around and who let you to the server console ?

Comment: All the blocks I have are related to a proxy,  HTTP request are accepted then the proxy tries to connect to the remote backends (this from my understanding may not be `locally-originated`) by using `block in` solve the problem but I would like to better understand if the why of this

Comment: Short answer - no. No, you don’t need all of these rules. Since you don’t understand how pf is working, you need to start with something fresh and simple. Yet equivalent to what you have and not interfering with your services. You can use the configuration proposed or keep searching for answers, it’s up to you.

Comment: I am indeed asking because with your configuration I still have the problem, that's why I post the `sysctl` settings since I thought that they may be affecting the `pf` rules

Comment: Show me the tcpdump output from pflog0 then.

Comment: Nah, this isn’t a paid techsupport.

Comment: Anyway, I see many `TCP retransmission` I have a guess is related to the `net.inet.tcp.msl`

Comment: Flush out that nonsense and reboot. I see only two reasonable settings - `kern.ipc.shmmax` and `kern.ipc.somaxconn` but I doubt you need these values.

Comment: From the `tcpdump` I see `[block bge0/0] 80 → 28650 [RST, PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=193` (https://imgur.com/532Szwq) one backend was returning 504 but output was blocked